# Что будет если передать массив в метод, который изменит его значения, изменятся ли они вне метода?

Tags: java

Что будет если передать массив в метод, который изменит его значения, изменятся ли они вне метода? Почему? А если передать примитив?

Comment: Зачем спрашивать - напишите код и проверьте.

Comment: 1) В зависимости от того какие объекты/примитивы содержатся в массиве и как именно они были "изменены" внутри метода -- могут измениться, а могут и остаться прежними. 2) Философский вопрос. 3) Примитив не изменится.

Comment: @AlexRudenko спасибо за ответ!

Comment: собственно, одна из практик заключается в том, чтобы не менять значения в функциях, а возвращать новое значение. Но это не всегда применимо, в том числе по соображениям эффективности.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запомни раз и навсегда! **в java всё передаётся по значению (pass by value).**

Это значит, что при передаче в метод примитива, у нас создаётся копия, ты можешь крутить и менять её значение внутри метода как угодно, но на само значение это никак ни повлияет.

```
public class Solution {

    static void test(int num) {
        System.out.println(num); // копия
        num += 1; // пробуем увеличить на 1
        System.out.println("после увеличения " + num);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 5;

        test(a);
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

вывод -

```
5  
после увеличения 6  
5
```

А вот со ссылкой посложнее.
На примере массива, массив - это объект, находящийся в куче(она же хип), который может хранить данные, например примитивы.
Передавая массив(объект) в метод, мы получаем копию ссылки, по ссылке мы можем изменить состояние объекта в хипе, но не можем поменять саму ссылку.

```
public class Solution {

    static void test(int[] arr, int[] arr2) {
        arr[0] = 777; // меняем значение 1го элемента в массиве

        arr = arr2;//указываем ссылкой на другой массив
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); // вывод [0]

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {1, 2, 3};
        int[] arr2 = {0};

        test(arr, arr2); 
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); // вывод [777, 2, 3]
    }
}
```

Нечто похожее происходит и с ключевым словом `final`
если обозначить примитив словом `final` мы не можем изменить значение, если пометить ссылочный тип, значение можем менять (кроме immutable объектов), а вот адрес, куда указывает ссылка нет.