# Не находит метод класса

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему компилятор не находит метод messwithCat(), хотя предыдущий метод getName() выполняеться

```
public class Main
{
   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Cat cat1 = new Cat ("Jimbo");
        cat1.getName();
        messWithcat(cat1); // why this is not working ?
        cat1.getName();
    }
}

class Cat
{
    
    private String catName;
    
    Cat (String name)
    {
        catName = name;
    }
    
    void getName()
    {
        System.out.println(catName);
    }
    void messWithcat(Cat a)
    {
        a = new Cat ("Kokos");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не находит, т.к. надо вызывать метод у обьекта `cat1.messWithcat(cat1);`, также, как ты вызывал метод `cat1.getName();`

чтобы данный метод вызывался именно с таким написанием `messWithcat(cat1);`
то надо метод перенести в класс `main` и добавить `static`

```
class Main {
    static void messWithcat(Cat a) {
        a = new Cat("Kokos");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat cat1 = new Cat("Jimbo");
        cat1.getName();
        messWithcat(cat1); 
        cat1.getName();
    }
}
```

если же оставить его в классе кот, то тоже добавляем `static` и вызываем через класс `Cat.messWithcat(cat1);`

далее отвечу на вопрос почему не меняется имя. Если добавить в `messWithcat` вызов `getName`

```
static void messWithcat(Cat a) {
        a = new Cat("Kokos");
        a.getName();
    }
```

вывод будет

```
Jimbo
Kokos
Jimbo
```

у тебя класс кот  Immutable (неизменяемый, нету сеттера и приватное поле - аналогия класс String) и передавая объект в метод, мы получаем копию ссылки указывающий на обьект в хипе, в методе ты можешь изменять копию обьекта по этой ссылке, но на сам обьект это никак не влияет.

а чтобы изменить обьект, надо изменить метод и в мейне присвоить ссылке возврат из метода

```
 static Cat messWithcat(Cat a) {
        a = new Cat("Kokos");
        a.getName(); //Kokos
        return a;
    }  

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cat cat1 = new Cat("Jimbo");
    cat1.getName();
    cat1 = Cat.messWithcat(cat1);
    cat1.getName(); //Kokos
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, затупил с вызовом метода.
Но вопрос:
`передавая объект в метод, мы получаем копию ссылки указывающий на обьект в хипе, в методе ты можешь изменять копию обьекта по этой ссылке, но на сам обьект это никак не влияет.`

Если обстрагироваться от моего метода, то это так и работает же.
По копии ссылки - можно изменять обьект, главное не "присваивать" ей новый.
Просто в моем примере, копия ссылки смотрит на другой, новый обьект и все изменения происходят с ним, а не с предыдущим.

Верно?

Как правильно называеться, когда в методе ссылке "присваиваеться" новый обьект? Инициализация?

Comment: @Mr.StupidQuestions инициализация - это первичное присвоение значения... у тебя  Immutable (неизменяемый) класс поэтому через ссылку нельзя изменить, в методе работа происходит с копией ссылки, переприсвоить её нельзя, только если повторно присвоить новое значение ссылке... перечитай ещё раз ответ, попробуй разные варианты в ide, похожий ответ был (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1342758/Что-будет-если-передать-массив-в-метод-который-изменит-его-значения-изменятся/1342873#1342873)

Answer (score 2):

Потому что `messWithcat` как и `getName` принадлежит какому-то классу. `getName` вы вызываете у объекта `cat1`, а второй...получается у текущего (`Main`)

Comment: Но это не единственная проблема кода астора...